# Changing component onPress but doesn't render | React Native

Tags: react-native

In some part of my app, I want to change to different components depending on which button I click.  I tried ChatGPT, it somewhat works. It works when navigating but when changing component it doesn't show. Also tried Text but it doesn't show. Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import Example from '../components/Example';

const ComponentOne = () => (
  <View>
    <Text>Component One</Text>
  </View>
);

const ComponentTwo = () => (
  <View>
    <Text>Component Two</Text>
  </View>
);

const ComponentThree = () => (
  <View>
    <Example/>
  </View>
);

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [activeComponent, setActiveComponent] = useState(ComponentOne);

  const handlePress = (component) => {
    setActiveComponent(component);
  };

  const renderActiveComponent = () => {
    switch (activeComponent) {
      case ComponentOne:
        return <ComponentOne />;
      case ComponentTwo:
        return <ComponentTwo />;
      case ComponentThree:
        return <ComponentThree />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePress(ComponentOne)}>
        <Text>Button One</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePress(ComponentTwo)}>
        <Text>Button Two</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePress(ComponentThree)}>
        <Text>Button Three</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {renderActiveComponent()}
    </View>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
export default function MyComponent() {
    const [id, setId] = useState(0)

    const RenderActiveComponent = useCallback(() => {
        switch (id) {
            case 0:
                return <ComponentOne />
            case 1:
                return <ComponentTwo />
            case 2:
                return <ComponentThree />
            default:
                return null
        }
    }, [id])

    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setId(0)}>
                <Text>Button One</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setId(1)}>
                <Text>Button Two</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setId(2)}>
                <Text>Button Three</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <RenderActiveComponent />
        </View>
    )
}
```